# Adding value if a different cell is ticked

Tags: excel, count, formula, percentage, countif

I'm trying to setup a spreadsheet to add up percentages when a task is complete. I've included a link to a small example below

[image]

What I want to happen is if a x or similar is put in and of the cells along the 3 row, then the percentage above that cell in the 2 row is added to the total in G3. I've tried using countif but I'm not sure it's even the right formula to use

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this VERY easily using the [SUMIF()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) function.
For example, supposing you wanted to sum if there was an `x` anywhere in row 3, your formula would look as follows:

```
=SUMIF(A3:F3,"x",A2:F2)
```

Hope this does the trick!

Comment: I forgot all about sumif and now I feel stupid. Guess it shows how long it's been since I used excel.

Comment: Glad it worked!! Also remember, since you're new to SO, to mark the answer as your solution so as to let other people know it's solved.